# Error While Showing Alert

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I am creating a signup screen and using firebase sdk on backend . i have add some if Conditions in my signup form and when ever if a textfield is left empty in form and register button is pressed i am showing a `UIAlertView` with a Title,Message and ok Button . but i am seeing a Thread exception while running app which says

> Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is < UIAlertController: 0x7fb750849200>.

and show stack and at the end of error stack it says

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

code for my alertfunction is

```
func ShowAlert(Title:String,Message:String){

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: Title, message: Message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true)
    }))

    alert.present(alert,animated: true)
}
```

i am feeling is that its some main thread issue but i don't know how to resolve.

Comment: Can you post more error detail? Where is this function? In UIViewController?

Comment: Please **read** the error message **carefully**, it tells you exactly what's wrong  (***present** ... view controller **on itself***).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current view controller should present the alert so just …

```
present(alert,animated: true)
```

rather than

```
alert.present(alert,animated: true)
```

---

*Update*

From your comment, it sounds like you're trying to present the alert on a background thread. *In addition to the above*, you should always present alerts (or perform any UI action) on the main thread…

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    showAlert(title: "My title", message: "My Message")
}
```

---

**Side note**

All variables, parameters  and func names in Swift should begin with a lower case letter, e.e.g

```
func showAlert(title: String, message: String)
```

instead of

```
func ShowAlert(Title:String,Message:String)
```

Comment: it doest display the alert box if i replace alert.present(alert,animated: true) with present(alert,animated: true)

Comment: `func showAlert(title:String, message:String)` => `func showAlert(title: String, message: String)` with space after ":" should be even better.

Comment: I used 
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    showAlert(title: "My title", message: "My Message")
}
but now its showing a different error : 'Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is <UIAlertController: 0x7fa80e0b6400>.

Comment: Please read my full answer. You need to do both things. Present from self, _and_ on the main queue

Comment: great , it worked . actually it was  self.present(alert,animated: true)

Comment: actually i am new to IOS thats why doing silly things . besides , Thanks again Brother